# Difference between vue.js development and minified versions?

Tags: vue.js

If i use minified file - next code runs OK:

```
<div id="app">
{{ bus.someVar }} -- {{ myVar }}
</div>
<script>
var bus = new Vue({
  data: {
    someVar: 'Variable from BUS'
  }
})
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myVar: 'Variable from MAIN VM'
  }
});
</script>
```

But with development version it says "Property or method 'bus' is not defined". Is that normal behavior ?

Comment: The dev version warning points to the standard behavior. That working in production version seems very much like a bug. If you define `bus` after `vm`, for instance, it won't work.

Comment: Of course it not gonna work if i define bus after vm, but it also not work if i define before. Problem is not about defining order. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRGvZy just remove ".min" in cdn file and error will come

Comment: This is what I mean by `bus` after `vm`: https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/jzMoBO It is `.min` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you keep telling it ? There is nothing related with hoisting in this question

Comment: I don't mean it is related to hoisting, I mean Vue picks up from the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the non-minified version, Vue will check if the variables exists before rendering. Since `bus.someVar` doesn't exist in the `vm` instance, Vue throws an error and halts.

In the minified version, there's no such verification, so the render function goes all the way.

"going all the way" means the render function will pick up from the outer (in your case the global) scope any variable that is not present in the instance.

To understand better, let's look at the the `render` function that is generated from the template.

Considering the template:

```html
<div id="app">
{{ bus.someVar }} -- {{ myVar }}
</div>
```

Vue generates the following render function:

```js
function() {
  with(this) {
    return _c('div', {
      attrs: {
        "id": "app"
      }
    }, [_v("\n" + _s(bus.someVar) + " -- " + _s(myVar) + "\n")])
  }
}
```

"Expanding" the name of the functions it will be:

```js
function() {
  with(this) {
    return createElement('div', {
      attrs: {
        "id": "app"
      }
    }, [createTextVNode("\n" + toString(bus.someVar) + " -- " + toString(myVar) + "\n")])
  }
}
```

If you take some time to read, it makes sense that is the generated render function for the mentioned template.

Now, when that function runs in the `vm` Vue instance, the `this` is `vm`.

Due to the presence of the [**`with(this)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), the code above will resolve `myVar` to `this.myVar` which is the same as `vm.myVar`. Now, similarly, since `bus` is not a property of `vm` it will fallback to the outer context, which is `window`. That's when it finds the other `bus` Vue instance.

So, to put in a few words: **whatever variable that does not exist in the current Vue instance, *minified* Vue will pick up from the global scope**.

It seems confusing because `bus` in the question example is another Vue instance, but that's just coincidence. To prove my point, have a look at the demo below. `bus` is just an object that belongs to the global scope and Vue picks it up.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{ bus.someVar }} -- {{ myVar }}
</div>

<script>
var bus = {someVar: 'Variable from (just an object) BUS'}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myVar: 'Variable from MAIN VM'
  }
});

console.log('bus it at the global scope:', bus.someVar);
console.log('bus is not at vm.bus:', vm.bus);
</script>
```

Comment: It is not a coincidence, bus is this case used as vuex, and it was doing well until i tried non-minified version. So minified and non-minified have different render functions ? My main question is Why non-minified not picking variables from global scope and which behavior is right ?

Comment: The non-minified does not pick from global scope because the checks/verifications are in place and, when they find that the variable doesn't exist in the Vue instance, they throw an error which stops the Vue instance from initializing. In the minified version there are no such checks (they are removed so the vue file is smaller). The correct behavior is the one of the non-minified version: every variable you use or try to render should be in your Vue instance. In the minified version it picks from `window` just by accident. In the future this may be removed.

Comment: What's verdict? I'm curious if it addressed the issue you pointed.

Comment: Verdict is - non-minified version sux. That render function kinda complicated for me right now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Uhm. Yeah. Anyway, we are supposed to follow what the non-minified version advises. It's the standard behavior. 